# CameraX: How to set background of PreviewView?

Tags: android, android-camera, drawable, android-camerax

By default, while flipping the camera, the screen blanks out for a while until the camera starts. I want to change that behavior a bit.

I want the last frame to be blurred out and set until the new binded Camera instance gets created. I tried using `getBitmap()` along with `BitmapDrawable` and `setBackground()` but that doesn't really seem to work (the screen is still blank).

Code:

```
    void startCamera(final boolean forced){

        if(!forced && camera!=null) return;

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .build();

        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(this.cameraSelector)
                .build();

        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .build();

        ImageCapture.Builder builder = new ImageCapture.Builder();

        final ImageCapture imageCapture = builder
                .setTargetRotation(this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
                .build();

        Bitmap b = mPreviewView.getBitmap();

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(mPreviewView.getSurfaceProvider());

        mPreviewView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b));

        // Unbind/close all other camera(s) [if any]
        cameraProvider.unbindAll();

        // Get a camera instance bound to the lifecycle of this activity
        camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis, imageCapture);

        // Focus camera on touch/tap
        mPreviewView.setOnTouchListener(this);

        start_auto_focus();
    }
```

Function to blur bitmap

```
    private Bitmap blurRenderScript(Bitmap smallBitmap, int radius) {

        final float defaultBitmapScale = 0.1f;

        int width  = Math.round(smallBitmap.getWidth() * defaultBitmapScale);
        int height = Math.round(smallBitmap.getHeight() * defaultBitmapScale);

        Bitmap inputBitmap  = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(smallBitmap, width, height, false);
        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

        RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, inputBitmap);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);
        theIntrinsic.setRadius(radius);
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

        return outputBitmap;
    }
```

Is there any way to override the blank screen behavior?

Comment: That is weird , might be the device issue that you are using maybe . Because I have using CameraX for a while now and I never faced this issue . Also the flipping is almost instant . Might be you have bad code .

Comment: Oh...maybe I haven't done it correctly...I shared the code in the answer.

Comment: Can you share a gif while flipping the camera

Comment: Sure, please give me 2 minutes

Comment: I have a Pixel device..So I don't think the device is the issue

Comment: I dont find anything wrong with your code , unless your mechanism of setting Front / Rear Camera bottlenecks .Weird tho  I would suggest you to clone the CameraX code provided by the officials and test the code on your device . If it remains the same , then the issue persist within the library / methodological . I agree that pixels are great and there might not be an issue with the same  , tho try testing on another device .

Comment: I had already built that app before...The delay is the same. Is there any way I can set the background of the preview to resolve the same issue?

Comment: However, it works fine for the default AOSP camera app for some reason

Comment: Yeah that is built native so has to be good. I'll try and experiment your usecase and revert

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot for the help 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved your question, doing so by using [this BlurImageView](https://github.com/jgabrielfreitas/BlurImageView) as the preview overlay, using a value animator to change the blur level automatically, and using a PreviewView callback for when the preview is visible/not visible.

**Setting up ValueAnimator:** (used to change the blur level automatically for a progressing blur animation)

```kotlin
// Initializing the preview animator with value to blur
val previewAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(6, 12, 18, 24, 25)
// Setting animation duration
previewAnimator.duration = 2000
// Adding listener for every value update of the animation
previewAnimator.addUpdateListener { animator ->
    // Blurring the preview when it is not visible
    blurOverlayImageView.setBlur(animator.animatedValue as Int)
}
// Adding action that is invoked on animation start
previewAnimator.doOnStart {
    // Setting the current preview frame as the canvas bitmap
    blurOverlayImageView.setImageBitmap(previewView.bitmap)
}
// Adding action that is invoked on animation cancel
previewAnimator.doOnCancel {
    // Removing the blurred preview to reveal the current actual preview
    blurOverlayImageView.setImageBitmap(null)
}
```

*The duration of the animation is 2 seconds, because 2 seconds is longer than the time it takes for the preview to restart, so this way the animation can be canceled before it is done, because after it is done it cannot be canceled so the callback for removing the last preview image will not trigger

*Start the previewAnimator before every time you restart the camera

*blurOverlayImageView - the preview overlay blur image view

**Callback for preview visibility:**

Check out the [answer](https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/XXTrQSKabmw) to my question in the Android CameraX Discussion Group for how to set a callback for the preview visibility - use: `previewView.previewStreamState.observe(previewObserver)`

*previewObserver - An Observer object used to observe changes in the PreviewView.StreamState

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! The problem is solved. I have added the function to blur a bitmap in the question's description and I have taken the last frame (bitmap) before unbinding the camera (although it can be taken at a later stage).