# Blur CameraX preview

Tags: android, android-camera, android-drawable, android-camerax

I am using CameraX library to build the camera preview for a layout and I want to blur the preview. I search a lot of methods but most of them are outdated or too complicated.

Now I am trying to refer to the blur method in [CameraX: How to set background of PreviewView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68979531/camerax-how-to-set-background-of-previewview), but my camera preview still do not blur.

I tried capturing the camera preview as texture view and convert it to bitmap, then use renderscript to blur it. However, my log keep showing "Camera preview bitmap is null".

MainActivity.kt

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)

        cameraPreview = findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        cameraBtn = findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
        blurOverlayImageView = findViewById(R.id.blurOverlay);

        // Request camera permission and initialize CameraX

            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), CAMERA_PERM_CODE
                )
            }


        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture?.addListener({
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture?.get()
            bindPreview(cameraProvider)
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))

        cameraBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, CameraActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
    }

    private fun bindPreview(cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider?) {
        // Configure the preview use case
        val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build()

        // Connect the preview to the PreviewView
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(cameraPreview.surfaceProvider)

        // Unbind any previous use cases before rebinding
        try {
            cameraProvider?.unbindAll()

            // Bind the camera use cases to the cameraProvider
            val camera = cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview)
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            // Handle exceptions here
        }
    }


    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture?.get()
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        // Initialize the preview animator for continuous blur
        initializePreviewAnimator()

        val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .build()
            .also { it.setSurfaceProvider(cameraPreview.surfaceProvider) }

        try {
            cameraProvider?.unbindAll()
            val camera = cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview
            )
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            // Handle exceptions here
        }
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERM_CODE) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission is Required to Use the camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun blurRenderScript(smallBitmap: Bitmap, radius: Int): Bitmap? {
        val defaultBitmapScale = 0.1f
        val width = (smallBitmap.width * defaultBitmapScale).roundToInt()
        val height = (smallBitmap.height * defaultBitmapScale).roundToInt()
        val inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(smallBitmap, width, height, false)
        val outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap)
        val renderScript = RenderScript.create(this)
        val theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript))
        val tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, inputBitmap)
        val tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap)
        theIntrinsic.setRadius(radius.toFloat())
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn)
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut)
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap)
        return outputBitmap
    }

    private fun initializePreviewAnimator() {
        // Initializing the preview animator with values to blur
        previewAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(6, 12, 18, 24, 25)
        // Set the animation to repeat infinitely
        previewAnimator.repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
        previewAnimator.repeatMode = ValueAnimator.RESTART

        // Setting animation duration for each frame (adjust as needed)
        //previewAnimator.duration = 100 // Set the duration for each frame (in milliseconds)

        // Adding listener for every value update of the animation
        previewAnimator.addUpdateListener { animator ->
            // Get the current blur level from the animator
            val blurLevel = animator.animatedValue as Int
            // Capture the camera preview frame
            val cameraBitmap = captureCameraPreview()
            if (cameraBitmap != null) {
                // Blurring the captured frame using the blurRenderScript function
                val blurredBitmap = blurRenderScript(cameraBitmap, blurLevel)
                // Set the blurred bitmap as the ImageView's image
                blurOverlayImageView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap)
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Camera preview bitmap is null")
            }
        }

        // Start the previewAnimator when you start the camera
        previewAnimator.start()
    }

    private fun captureCameraPreview(): Bitmap? {
        val view = cameraPreview.getChildAt(0) as? TextureView
        return view?.bitmap
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the `PRIV` output of preview to `Bitmap` and using RenderScript to blur is highly inefficient. The recommended way of applying effects with CameraX is the [CameraEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraEffect) API. You will need to write OpenGL code for that. You can check out the code sample [here](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/camera/integration-tests/viewtestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/view/ToneMappingSurfaceProcessor.kt).

In that sample code, the [OpenGlRenderer](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/camera/camera-core/src/main/java/androidx/camera/core/processing/OpenGlRenderer.java) file contains the OpenGL code. When you copy this code, update the [fragment shader](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/37df1f7745e04a9c7e2a7fb60f7449491276916f/camera/camera-core/src/main/java/androidx/camera/core/processing/OpenGlRenderer.java#L96) to apply a blur effect. An example of a blur shader can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64837705/opengl-blurring). Or, you can just ask ChatGPT to update the sample code with blur effect.

Comment: Renderscript is deprecated. Any other solutions?

Comment: We can use Open GL to blur. Something like: https://g.co/gemini/share/0ab1a33b2306

Comment: ChatGPT solutions are generally not working solutions. Would you please write an answer if I create a new question and give you credit? I need to blur a Bitmap, not a View.

Comment: Unfortunately, a working solution with OpenGL is not trivial. I don't have the bandwidth to provide you the full solution. If your input is Bitmap, I suggest you using the deprecated Renderscript for now: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/camera/integration-tests/viewtestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/view/BlurBitmap.java

Comment: Otherwise, you can fork the GLRenderer here and update the shaders to blur. The Gemini generated code looks correct to me. However there might be bugs since it's untested. https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/camera/integration-tests/viewtestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/view/ToneMappingSurfaceProcessor.kt